# Laravel collection sortBy not taking effect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I'm trying to combine and sort the results from several db queries.

```
$events = collect();

$downedEvents = EventDowned::where('mission', $missionId)
   ->orderBy('mission_time', 'asc')
   ->get();

$events->push($downedEvents);

$getInOutEvents = EventGetInOut::where('mission', $missionId)
   ->orderBy('mission_time', 'asc')
   ->get();

$events->push($getInOutEvents);

$missileEvents = EventMissile::where('mission', $missionId)
   ->orderBy('mission_time', 'asc')
   ->get();

$events->push($missileEvents);

$flattenedEvents = $events->flatten();
$sortedEvents = $flattenedEvents->sortBy('mission_time');

return $sortedEvents->all();
```

The result looks like this:

[image: ss]

As you can see it has correctly combined the results, however they remain in their original query order, not sorted.

I've also tried

```
$sortedEvents = $flattenedEvents->sortBy(function($event) {
    return (int) $event->mission_time;
});
```

Comment: That would work if the items are associative arrays, provide your callback function to `sortBy` and try.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby

Comment: I've tried `$sortedEvents = $flattenedEvents->sortBy(function($event) { return $event->mission_time; });` but it has the same result

Comment: var_dump `$event->mission_time` and check the type

Comment: I thought that might be the case so I did try `return (int) $event->mission_time` with the same result

Comment: It seems right for me.. the only thing I can say is to debug it.. set breakpoints and dive deep into the `sortBy` code.
Don't worry it's a function of 10 lines. not a big deal

Comment: @ShadyAtef found the issue (see answer) sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A huge fail on my part, my pretty print JSON chrome extension was messing with the display order, viewing the raw response showed they were in fact sorted correctly... ::facepalm::

Comment: I will go back calmly to my AI study.,
But Good luck that you found it.

Comment: Lmao this saved me... Why would it do that!?

Comment: @Titan Really, that was the problem ?, Why do I have exactly the same problem and I have been trying to make the order work for hours and I have not managed any idea or recommendation? please

Comment: I experienced the same issue with Postman... The pretty response was not ordered and the Raw response was ordered like I wanted ! Thanks

Comment: Was pulling my hair out on this! For anyone reading, "JSON Formatter" for Chrome does this. Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

To extend on @Titan's answer, i guess the extensions/ postman maintain the array indexing order. Not really sure.

To get rid of that

```
return $collection->values();
```

Here is an example

```
$arr = collect([
  0 => [
      'name' => 'foo',
      'weight' => 70
  ],
  1 => [
      'name' => 'bar',
      'weight' => 80
  ]
 ]);

return $arr->sortByDesc('weight');
```

the extension will still keep the index order

```
return $arr->sortByDesc('weight')->values();
```

This will get the desired order.

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer! you saved my day dude!

Comment: That is it! 10th time that I've been here. Now its memorized, I promise!

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I came acoss a weird issue: If I save the sorted values again in the same field of the collection, the order was lost again. When I temporarely saved the sorted values in a variable, and unset the field before saving the variable in it again, it worked.